# Is is possible to set a default profile for different environments in EB CLI?

Tags: elastic-beanstalk

I have a project where the testing env is inside my company, and the production env is in the client's AWS account.

I was looking for a way to set two different profile names on my `project/.elasticbeanstalk/config.global.yml`, so the test environment uses the `test` branch and `proj-test` profile (from my `~/.aws/config` file), and there would be another set of branch-profile for the production version.

I only saw a `global.profile` key, and setting `profile` under `branch-defaults.<branchname>` or `environment-defaults.<env>` doesn't do anything.

Is that idea possible?
Is there any reference to available settings in these `config.yml` files?